# In Fear the Walking Dead, season 4, is there an inconsistency as to Madison's reunion with the group?

Tags: plot-explanation, fear-the-walking-dead

In season 4, at some point (I think in the "Just in Case" episode) Victor Strand recalls how he was saved by Madison (first from drowning, and then being nursed back to health).  But then in the episode "No One Dies" it is discovered that in fact Madison actually encountered the entire group (including Victor Strand) already reunited at a hotel.  Am I missing something, or is this an obvious inconsistency?